When developing Codeigniter projects, how can I prevent them from being unable to be updated?
Before I start my first Codeigniter3/4 project, I would like to clarify in advance and understand what I need to take into account so that I can continue to update Codeigniter in the future without much effort.
For example, if I make changes to the files belonging to Codeigniter, I would no longer be able to easily overwrite them in the future when an update appears.
Is there a specific procedure for this (except, of course, not to change these files in the first place :-) )?
I've already looked in the Codeigniter documentation, but unfortunately I didn't find anything there or I was looking for the wrong things.

For CodeIgniter 3, you can make changes to the core functionality by copying the core class you want to change from system/core into application/core and then modifying it - either replace the core class completely or extend it and change a few details. See: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html When you update CodeIgniter 3, you overwrite their system folder, so then the changes you made in application/core will still be preserved.

for CI 4.x, read through this
